# Yahoo Finance API - Failed to Open Stream HTTP request Failed

Tags: php, yahoo-finance

I have a web app that queries Yahoo Finance API for all the NASDAQ stocks only while the market is open. Usually it runs 179 tickers at a time and loops through a total of about 3000 tickers. For at least the past week, some or most of the queries will fail and throw an error in PHP: "Failed to open stream - HTTP request failed". I've tried running it from command line on the web server to make sure I'm not reaching the max hourly queries, and I've tried running the queries in my browser, both work fine. I've tried pausing the script between loops, still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I seem to be having the same problem.